# Zig-zag iterating array - speed optimizing

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, embedded

I have an array like so:

```
{
  1, 2, 3, 4,
  5, 6, 7, 8,
  9,10,11,12,
 13,14,15,16
}
```

and I need to iterate it in a zig-zag manner, like `1,2,3,4, 8,7,6,5, 9...`

It's easy, but there's very little space for overhead, so I need it to be as time-efficient as possible. Every extra cycle matters here.

This is what I have now:

```
#define send_colors_zigzag(io, colorz, width, height) do {                          \
    for(int8_t y = 0, uu=0, a=1; y < (height); y++, uu+=width, a *= -1) {           \
        uint8_t uup = uu + (a < 0 ? width : 0);                                     \
        for(uint8_t x = 0; x < (width); x++) {                                      \
            uint8_t pos = uup + a*x;                                                \
            const color_t clr = (colorz)[pos];                                      \
            send_one_color(io_pack(io), clr);                                       \
        }                                                                           \
    }                                                                               \
} while(0)
```

`send_one_color` is a macro that expands into a loop for the individual bits, and I'd rather not repeat it twice within this macro (need to keep it small).

I have a reason to do it as a macro, `io` and `io_pack` is some wizardry for pin aliasing which can't be done with a regular function.

I believe it loops right, but it's not fast enough (so it can't be used).

I'm working on an 8-bit micro, 16MHz.

---

For info, this version works (but the large inner macro is repeated twice, which I want to avoid):

```
#define send_colors_zigzag(io, colorz, width, height) do {                          \
    int8_t x;                                                                       \
    for(int8_t y = 0; y < (height); y++) {                                          \
        for(x = 0; x < (width); x++) {                                              \
            send_one_color(io_pack(io), (colorz)[y*width + x]);                     \
        }                                                                           \
        y++;                                                                        \
        for(x = width-1; x >=0; x--) {                                              \
            send_one_color(io_pack(io), (colorz)[y*width + x]);                     \
        }                                                                           \
    }                                                                               \
} while(0)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 8 ,7 , 6 ,5 ..`?

Comment: yeah, sorry. it should indeed

Comment: Since you have a working code, it might fit better [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: The code is not really "working", it maybe loops right but isn't fast enough to meet timing criteria, so in essence, it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check asm code and see what is doing slow down. Try to replace multiplication for addition.

Comment: My guess is that the part that is slowing you down the most is: `uint8_t uup = uu + (a < 0 ? width : 0);`. I am going to guess it fools the branch prediction mechanism, and thus at each iteration of the outer loop a lot of calculations are wasted. I'd try to see if it can be avoided. However, I am really not a low-level optimization expert - so I may be just shooting in the dark.

Comment: I tried to get a "lst" file, but there's no information about what's being done when I call this, but rather a huge chunk of assembler which I don't understand very well..

Comment: Are you sure it is the loop overhead that is the problem?  You can replace `a *= -1` with `a = -a`, eliminating a multiplication.  You can use a conditional instead of a multiplication calculating `pos`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'll give your ideas a go @JonathanLeffler.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that avoids as much arithmetic as possible, especially in the inner loop.

```
color_t* p = (colorz);
for (int8_t y = 0; y < (height); y++) {
    int8_t inc = y & 1 ? -1 : 1;
    if (y) {
        p += (width) + inc;
    }
    for (int8_t x = 0; x < (width); x++) {
        send_one_color(io_pack(io), *p);
        p += inc;
    }
}
```

You can save a few cycles with this variant if `height` is even, or if you don't mind undefined behavior (because `p` points beyond the end of `colorz`):

```
color_t* p = (colorz);
for (int8_t y = 0; y < (height); y++) {
    int8_t inc = y & 1 ? -1 : 1;
    for (int8_t x = 0; x < (width); x++) {
        send_one_color(io_pack(io), *p);
        p += inc;
    }
    p += (width) - inc;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try how this runs. Undefined behavior is fine, I'm sending the colors to LEDs and there's nothing past the real array size - so the garbage will go unnoticed.

Comment: @MightyPork it's irrelevant what's past the array size in memory. There's no out-of-bounds memory access in the code, but it's UB to increment a pointer beyond 1 location after the end of an array.

Comment: okay I tried it, unfortunately it doesn't work.. probably too much overhead, although I don't really understand what could be the issue